# Flask program to play audio files on iphone

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a home workout program that gives me audio cues for when to switch exercises, which exercises to do, etc... I have this working on my laptop using a small python program to play some short pre-recorded audio files (aiff format) at specified intervals.

However, I'd like to be able to run this program from my iPhone. I attempted to do this by setting up a Flask server on my computer. I can get the program to run via a web browser on the same machine hosting the server, but when I use a different computer or my iPhone, the audio still plays on the host computer's speakers, not the client as desired. The computer hosting the Flask server is running OS X 10.11.6. Here is a basic version of the program:

Flask Python:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('rockrings_stackoverflow.html')

@app.route('/click', methods=['POST'])
def start_workout():
    return workout.workout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

workout.py:

```
def workout():
    for minute in range(10):
        audio_file = homedir + '/audio_files/easy_workout_minute%i.aiff' % minute
        print audio_file
        os.system('afplay %s' % audio_file)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Hangboard Webtool! </h1>
    Click the button below to start the easy workout
    <br/><br/>

<form action="/click" method="post">
    <button type="submit" value="Easy workout">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What is a proper implementation (if there is one) with Flask?

Comment: You need to render your file in html and only this way your phone can play audio(via phone browser)

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? I am not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp and you need to include put absolute path to your file, that is reachable in browser.

Comment: The path is variable since I have 10 different files I am looping over in workout.py. The link does not explain how to use a variable filename in your html file. Can you show a simple example using Flask and html? If you answer it and it works I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I pointed you at your problem, you need somehow put that in audio format and render html. Another way is to streem your audio to page, but it's probably more complicated than the first one. It's easy to google.